# how to set opacity for my rectangle(drawingcontext)

Tags: c#, wpf, 2d, drawingcontext

**This is my rectangle**

```
protected void DrawRectangle(DrawingContext dc, Point point)
        {
            DrawingVisual drawingVisual = new DrawingVisual();
            using (DrawingContext drawContext = drawingVisual.RenderOpen())
            {
                Pen drawingPen = new Pen(ErrorBarBrush, ErrorBarThickness);
                dc.DrawRectangle(Brushes.Red,
                    new Pen(Brushes.Black, 5),
                    new Rect(new Point(point.X - 50, point.Y + 50),
                    new Point(point.X + 50, point.Y - 50)));
                dc.PushOpacity(2);

            }
        }
```

**So my question is how do i set my opacity, is this right way to do it?**

Comment: Just a note. It's pointless to create that DrawingVisual and call its RenderOpen method when you never use the returned DrawingContext.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(This is changing the opacity of the Rectangle)

Instead of passing Brushes.Red into the Rectangle make a new SolidColorBrush and set the opacity of the SolidColorBrush you pass into the Rectangle

```
SolidColorBrush rectBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
rectBrush.Opacity = 0.5; // or whatever

dc.DrawRectangle(rectBrush, ...
```

You'll need to do a similar thing for the Pen

Answer (score 1):

Simply

```
drawingVisual.Opacity = 0.5;
```